# Why is this responsive css not working?

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to revise the Portfolio Page Wordpress theme with the addition of a page wide graphic banner and type treatments.  Its a responsive theme, but I have apparently screwed things up.  The css uses a background-repeat on the x axis to repeat some wooden planks out for the full screen, and then places other graphics over it which center up responsively. 
Here's the css I'm talking about:

```
#bgImageCornerTL
{
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
margin-top:0px;
height: 274px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;
background-image:url(http://chalupaholics.com/bob/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/PanelWStripe.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position: center center;
}
#LogoContent {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -250px;
    width: 872px;
    height: 198px;
    z-index: 12;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("/bob/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/BufBobwords.png");
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

The repeat isn't working on the iphone. So, I wrote some css that should be run via a "media" query,  but my iphone isn't picking it up and the page still looks wrong.  (For the iphone, I'm using a single graphic for the header with the graphics and wooden planks flattened into one graphic.)  Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong?
Here's the CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

{
#bgImageCornerTL
    {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    height: 147px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    background-image:url(http://chalupaholics.com/bob/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/TopBannerIphone.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    }
#LogoContent,#Tasty,#Address,#Order {
    display:none;
}

}
```

and so on...

And here is the relevant area of the header.php file where I added some divs to handle the new graphics:

```
<div id="bgImageCornerTL"></div>
<div id="navwrap"></div>
</head>

<body>

<div id="LogoContent">
<div id="Tasty"></div>
<div id="Address"></div>
<div id="Order"></div>
</div>



<div id="wrapper">
```

and so on...
It looks fine on a regular sized screen, but breaks on the iphone.  I haven't tried other devices yet.

Here is the URL, if you want to take a look:

```
http://www.chalupaholics/bob/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra '{' above the #bgImageCornerTL selector in your media query

Comment: That was it!  Thanks for spotting that.  Made my day!